# Find the name of the delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

Say that I have the following class

```
public class Conditional 
{
    private readonly Func<Boolean> _conditional;

    public Conditional(Func<Boolean> test)
    {
        _conditional = test;
    }

    public override BehaviourReturnCode Behave()
    {
        var conditionalResult = _conditional.Invoke();
 //... keeps going
 }
```

so when I create an instance of Conditional, I would do something like

```
var isAlive = new Conditional(actor.IsAlive);
```

so the question is, how can I find out the method name of **_conditional** , in this case IsAlive ?

FYI _conditional.Method.Name doesn't do it :D

Cheers

Comment: So in your example you'd expect isAlive to be assigned "IsAlive"?

Comment: Are you concern about lambdas and anonomus delegates?

Comment: @Miau I have tried it and _conditional.Method.Name spits out "IsAlive". See https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6908215 - I'm running on Mono on Mac .NET 4.5.

Comment: Here is a link to a post that may help.   http://abdullin.com/journal/2008/12/13/how-to-find-out-variable-or-parameter-name-in-c.html

Comment: @Krumelur I can confirm that what you're saying is indeed true. Mono here too ! Miau you must understand that basically, a delegate is composed of 1 MethodInfo and 1 (possibly null) target object (representing the this parameter in case of instance method delegates). If you don't see the name of your method as you'd expect then maybe you're not paying attention. Maybe you're using a lambda which has a weird, compiler generated name and you thought you used a plain ol' method as the delegate's value.

Comment: `_conditional.Method.Name` most certainly *does* do it.  It works in several tests that I've done.  You'll need to provide a complete compilable example that shows otherwise to make your issue clear.

Comment: Delegate objects don't have names, they at most have a type. Conditional._conditional is the field of the class.  It has nothing to do with the delegate object, it merely stores a reference to it.  Fields have names, you can find them with typeof(Conditional).GetFields().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
Func<bool> UserIsAlive = () =>
    {
        return false;
    };

Func<bool> UserIsDead = UserIsAlive;
```

You have two local variables which reference the same lambda function.

Which one is the real name?  `UserIsAlive` or `UserIsDead`?

Hint:  It doesn't have a name.  It's a function.  If you want to name it in some way that's up to you to decide how you should do so.  Wrap it in a class?  Store it in a dictionary?  Pass the name to the function like so?

`var isAlive = new Conditional(actor.IsAlive, "IsAlive");`

Comment: Technically the anonymous method does have a name; the compiler will generate one for it's own internal use.  The spirit of the answer is still correct though.